# OrderBy predicate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I've got this code:

```js
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
   app.controller('RadioCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
     function($scope, $http) {
       $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows=5&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&id={index}').success(function(data) {
         $scope.people = data;
       })
     }
   ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Radio button</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section ng-controller="RadioCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="pepek.fname">
    <br>Ascended
    <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" checked>Descended
    <input type="radio" ng-model="direction" value="reverse">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Second name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter:pepek |orderBy:person.id">
          <td>{{person.id}}</td>
          <td>{{person.fname}}</td>
          <td>{{person.lname}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd like to click radio button Ascending or Descending and my table would be lined up by ID.
Even when i try simple `orderBy:id` or `orderBy:-id` or `orderBy:person.id` or `orderBy:id:reverse` or `orderBy:id:direction` non of those cases didn't lined up Ascending by ID it always does Descending and i don't know why. 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-repeat expression wasn't quite right. Should be something like:

```
ng-repeat="person in people| filter:pepek | orderBy:'id':reverse"
```

and the radio button declarations need to look like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="reverse" ng-value="false">Descended
<input type="radio" ng-model="reverse" ng-value="true">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
   app.controller('RadioCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
     function($scope, $http) {
       
       $scope.reverse = false;
       
       $http.jsonp('http://www.filltext.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&rows=5&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}&id={index}').success(function(data) {
         $scope.people = data;
       })
     }
   ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Radio button</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section ng-controller="RadioCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="pepek.fname">
    <br>Ascended
    <input type="radio" ng-model="reverse" ng-value="false">Descended
    <input type="radio" ng-model="reverse" ng-value="true">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Second name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter:pepek |orderBy:'id':reverse">
          <td>{{person.id}}</td>
          <td>{{person.fname}}</td>
          <td>{{person.lname}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your ID is perhaps being stored as a String value rather than integer. Try this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | orderBy:parseFloat(person.id)">
```

Comment: No didn't help although I can't figure out why it's always Descending real problem i want to achieve is radio button

Comment: Can you add a plunker with your sample json ??